# Stripe Checkout webhook events invoice editing with mandatory legal text

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

**Problem**:

I am using Stripe's Checkout platform to sell some subscriptions to my SaaS product.
In Germany, small businesses are exempt from VAT. However, they have to state in the invoice the legal text explaining why they are exempt. What needs to be written to invoice is decided with algorithm below:

```
if B2B:
  if DE:
    exemption_text
  else if EU:
    reverse_charge_text
  else:
    not_taxable_text
if B2C:
  exemption_text
```

Unfortunately, the only way I can know if this is a B2B sale, If customer selects `I am buying as a business` and enters a valid tax number in Stripe hosted checkout page. (**I do not want to add this to my onboarding flow as Stripe already has this feature**)

Then when the customer pays through Stripe's hosted checkout page, I get the `invoice.created` and `invoice.paid` webhook events successfully as well as the information about country and If this was a B2B sale. However, I cannot edit the invoice anymore as it is already paid.

**What I tried**:

My idea was to catch webhook event for `invoice.created` and then modify its' `footer` before the invoice is finalized as it is not possible to change the invoice after it is finalized. But, even though I try to update the invoice as soon as I catch `invoice.created`, when I try to update the footer I get an error like:

`Error: Finalized invoices can't be updated in this way`

Also in webhook I am able to see that `checkout.session.completed`, `invoice.created` and `invoice.paid` events are posted the same second which removes the possibility to do anything with the webhook events related to invoice's legal text.

I am just trying to figure out if this is a company buying my product and If so put a specific text depending on the country to invoice before invoice is finalized.
Would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm hitting similar issues where I'd like to display a custom field on the invoice, but I can't as it is created automatically.

Comment: I still could not find a solution. It seems the only way is to modify onboarding flow to collect this information. Or disable B2B option all together.  i.e. Disable VAT Id collection.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way for you to update the invoice while the choice is being made on the Checkout page OR after Checkout Session has been completed.

Edit: Forgot that `invoice_data` parameter can only be set for `payment` mode Checkouts as pointed out by a comment.

<s>You'd likely want to alter the flow a bit and check if the customer is buying for a business before redirecting them to a Checkout Session & if so, then you can set the text while creating a Checkout Session using [this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-invoice_creation-invoice_data) parameter.</s>

Comment: This does not work. The "invoice_creation" parameter cannot only be used with sessions of type "subscription", which is the situation OP found themselves in.